# Class Method not using the class variable

Tags: c#

I'm working through a couple coding exercises to teach myself C# and have gotten stuck for a couple of days now trying to calculate different time periods on other planets and it's time to tap out and ask for help. I've at least gotten rid of the errors and it's starting to return something but now for the life of me I can't figure out why `seconds` won't store in a stable way to then have methods call on. It's just returning zero. Please see the below code.

```
    public class SpaceAge
    {
        public long seconds;

        public SpaceAge(long seconds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Space Age in Seconds:" + seconds); 
        }

        public double OnEarth()
        {
            double result = seconds / 31557600;
            return result;
        }
        public double OnMercury()
        {
            double result = seconds * 0.2408467;
            return result;
        }
    }  

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("**Main Function Executing**");
             var age = new SpaceAge(10000000000);
             Console.WriteLine("Earth years:" + age.OnEarth());
             Console.WriteLine("Mercury years:" + age.OnMercury());       
        }
    }
```

It returns:

```
BBs-iMac:space-age bb$ dotnet run
**Main function executing**
Space Age in Seconds:10000000000
Earth years:0
Mercury years:0
```

Comment: You're never setting `seconds` in your `SpaceAge` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor has two different variables named `seconds`: the class member, and the argument. You need to do this:

```
public SpaceAge(long seconds)
{
    this.seconds = seconds;
    Console.WriteLine("Space Age in Seconds:" + seconds); 
}
```

Additionally, the arithmetic in `OnEarth()` happens entirely in integer space, which means any decimal part of the results would be truncated. You need to make sure at least one side of your division operations is a floating point type:

```
public class SpaceAge
{
    public long seconds;

    public SpaceAge(long seconds)
    {
        this.seconds = seconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Space Age in Seconds:" + seconds); 
    }

    public double OnEarth()
    {
        //the "D" at the end of the number means it is a double, not an int.
        return seconds / 31557600D;
    }
    public double OnMercury()
    {
        return seconds * 0.2408467D;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialise your field.  Also, because `seconds` is `long` you should use a `D` suffix on your divisors.

```
using System;

public class SpaceAge
{
    public long seconds;
    public SpaceAge(long seconds)
    {
        this.seconds = seconds; // missing
        Console.WriteLine("Space Age in Seconds:" + seconds);
    }

    public double OnEarth()
    {
        double result = seconds / 31557600D; // add an 'D'
        return result;
    }

    public double OnMercury()
    {
        double result = seconds * 0.2408467D; // add an 'D'
        return result;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("**Main Function Executing**");
        var age = new SpaceAge(10000000000);
        Console.WriteLine("Earth years:" + age.OnEarth());
        Console.WriteLine("Mercury years:" + age.OnMercury());
    }
}
```

Output:

Without 'D' suffix

```
**Main Function Executing**
Space Age in Seconds:10000000000
Earth years:316
Mercury years:2408467000
```

With 'D' suffix:

```
**Main Function Executing**
Space Age in Seconds:10000000000
Earth years:316.88087814029
Mercury years:2408466935.15778
```

Comment: "D" might be better, since he wants a double result.

Comment: Thanks for putting all the pieces together.